# check and replace double expression in string PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This is my string for example:

```
$x = " i love you/i love her/you love me/you love me "
```

and i wanted in every blank space to put - so i use:

```
$y = preg_replace(" ","-",$x);
```

and i get:

```
  $y = " i-love-you/i-love-her/you-love-me/you-love-me "
```

in this string i have double expresion YOU LOVE ME, in that case when i have that, i want to add in other not one -, i want to add 2 --

so my final string will look like:

```
$y = " i-love-you/i-love-her/you-love-me/you--love--me "
```

Can you help me with these, cause if i use preg replace it will have influence on whole string?

Comment: so you want to add -- in the last one always

Comment: Given ` I love you/you love me/I love you/you love her/you love me/she loves me`, what do you expect

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes, not always, only if tha last one is duplicate of previous one

Comment: You could use a capture group quantifier to look for duplicates that are next to each other like [`/\/([^\/]+)\/(\1)/`](https://regex101.com/r/woDgfE/1) then do some additional replacements based on capture group 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This simple code

```
$x = "i love you/i love her/you love me/you love me";
$strArr = explode("/",$x);
$temp = array();
foreach($strArr as $value){
    if(in_array($value,$temp)){
       $result[]=str_replace(" ","--",$value);    
    }else{
       $result[]=str_replace(" ","-",$value);
    }
    $temp[] = $value;
}
echo implode("/",$result);
```

Comment: This code is great, i wanted to use it for another string like this:

    $x = "cellular & data radios|modems|analog modems|analog--modems|analog--modems"

In this case i have triple double expression, what to change in code, to only the last one have --?

Comment: Add below code inside the in_array condition
 $tmp = array_count_values($temp);
      if($tmp[$value]>1)
         $result[]=str_replace(" ","---",$value);
      else
         $result[]=str_replace(" ","--",$value);

Comment: No you didnt understand me very well, if i have triple case, then i want only to add two lines -- in the last one, and it the first two only one line -
like this:
 $x = "cellular & data radios|modems|analog-modems|analog-modems|analog--modems"

Comment: Try this inside the in_array()condition
$key = array_search($value,array_reverse($temp,true));
      if(!empty($key))
         $result[$key] = str_replace(" ","-",$value);
      $result[]=str_replace(" ","--",$value);

Comment: Dude you are awsome! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can to do it by both ways like **regex** or **non-regex** way but this what I got in my mind with `array_count_values()` and `str_replace()`. Hope it'll help you **:)**

```
<?php
$x = " i love you/i love her/you love me/you love me ";
$sentence = explode('/',trim($x));

$value_counts = array_count_values($sentence);
$expected_result = [];
foreach($value_counts as $k=>$v){
    if($v<2){
        $expected_result[] = str_replace(' ','-',$k);
    }else{
        $expected_result[] = str_replace(' ','-',$k);
        for($i=2;$i<=$v;$i++){
            $expected_result[] = str_replace(' ','--',$k); 
        }
    }
}

echo " ".implode('/', $expected_result)." ";
```

**Output:**

```
 i-love-you/i-love-her/you-love-me/you--love--me
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/Hh6Pj

Answer (score 0):

Another more verbose and likely slower method :{

```
function format_string($x)  
{
    //trim whitespace to avoid "-" at beginning and end 
    $x = str_replace(" ","-",trim($x));
    // create an array of each entry 
    $entries = explode("/", $x);
    //count each entry 
    $entry_counts = array_count_values($entries);

    foreach($entry_counts as $string => $count){
        if($count == 2){
            $needs_updating = $string;  
        }
    }

    if(isset($needs_updating)){
        foreach($entries as $index => &$entry){
            if($entry == $needs_updating){
                $entries[$index] = str_replace("-", "--",$entry);
            }
        }

        return implode("/", $entries); 
     }

    return implode("/", $entries); 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the original string, you can match the slash separated phrases and do the space replacement in a callback function that keeps track of phrases as it goes. If one of the phrases has already appeared, replace the spaces with double dashes instead of single.

```
$pattern = '/(?<=^|\/).+?(?=\/|$)/';
$phrases = [];
$y = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($phrase) use (&$phrases) {
    $separator = in_array($phrase[0], $phrases) ? '--' : '-';
    $phrases[] = $phrase[0];
    return str_replace(' ', $separator, $phrase[0]);
}, trim($x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my go:

```
$x = " i love you/i love her/you love me/you love me ";

$x = preg_replace_callback('/([^\/]+)\/(\1)?/', function($match){
    if(isset($match[2])){
        return str_replace(' ', '-', trim($match[1])).'/'.str_replace(' ', '--', trim($match[2]));
    }else{
        return str_replace(' ', '-', trim($match[1])).'/';
    }
}, $x);

echo $x;
```

Output

```
i-love-you/i-love-her/you-love-me/you--love--me
```

And the smallified version of it:

```
$x = " i love you/i love her/you love me/you love me ";
echo preg_replace_callback('/([^\/]+)\/(\1)?/',function($m){return isset($m[2])?str_replace(' ','-',trim($m[1])).'/'.str_replace(' ','--',trim($m[2])):str_replace(' ','-',trim($m[1])).'/';},$x);
```